# SQL Server: How to edit a view without scripting it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

How can i edit the definition of a `view` without having to "script" it in SSMS?

The previous easy-to-use tools from Microsoft let me:

1. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. *wait a moment*
3. Make change
4. Carefully move mouse to large `OK` button
5. Click `OK`
6. <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>
7. `goto 1`

With SSMS i've having a much more tedious time of it:

1. Carefully move mouse to <sub>small</sub> view to script
2. Right-click
3. *wait a moment*
4. Carefully move mouse to <sub>small</sub> menu option `Script View as`
5. Carefully move mouse to <sub>small</sub> menu option `ALTER TO`
6. Carefully move mouse to <sub>small</sub> menu option `New Query Editor Window`
7. *wait a moment*
8. Press `F5`
9. Carefully move mouse to <sub>tiny <sub>`x`</sub></sub> icon
10. Click close button
11. Carefully move mouse to large `No` button
12. Click `No`
13. `goto 1`

i'm really not interested in scripting my view to a new query editor window. i want to edit the view definition. Microsoft seemed to implement editing the definition of a view by resorting to an `ALTER VIEW` in a new query window.

Is there a way to view/edit the definition of (a lot) of views, without having to resort to the UI tedium introduced with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: I'm curious what "easy-to-use" tools you are talking about?

Comment: Steps 9 to 13 are off. If you're doing step thirteen, just stop before step 9.

Comment: @Joel Coel: If i don't close the tabs then after 5 or 6 dozen SSMS really begins to get sluggish.

Comment: @Seth Spearman: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215396(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: What @Joel is trying to say is, instead of opening a new window every time you make your changes in the same window and hit F5.  You don't need to reopen the view every time you want to make a change to it.

Comment: i see the confusion. i'm not editing one view (over and over). i'm going through dozens of views, one by one.

Comment: @Ian Ah, that makes more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could give us a hint as to what the aforementioned "easy-to-use tools from Microsoft" were?

There is a View Designer in SSMS as an option.  In Object Explorer, right-click a view, click `Design` or right-click the Views node and click `New View...`, but it is a bit limited.  If your views are at all complex (ie- much beyond simple JOINs) you're pretty much going to be scripting it.

Comment: It doesn't matter, or affect the question, or answer. It's a tool that SQL Server 2005 refuses to accept a connection from. And since it's not supported since 2002, and has not been updated for 64-bit Windows, i can no longer run it without `Windows XP Mode`. Finally, the view designer modifies view definition formatting, and removes comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the view.
2. Left click on Design
3. Make your changes in the query window.
4. Close the designer and click on any prompts that come up

Comment: Designer modifies the formatting, and removes comments, from views.

Comment: He more than likely, by his description, was previously using some kind of designer and made no mention of retaining formatting or comments ;)